# Windows Phone 8.1 ScrollView: auto-height

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollview

I would like to ceate a text block inside a scroll view. I want the scroll view to be automatic on every device and every screen size. But for the moment, I am forced to fix an height, in pixels. Otherwise, the scroll view will adapt to the text size... Without doing its scrolling job.
How to do this properly?

Thanks!

EDIT: here is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" IsEnabled="True" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="titleBlock" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="48"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="subtitleBlock" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontStyle="Italic"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="dateBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontSize="24"/>

        <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="370" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,15,0,0" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" AllowDrop="False" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="True" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" IsHoldingEnabled="True" >
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock x:Name="descriptionBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontSize="14.667"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Button x:Name="buttonViewFlyer" Click="buttonViewFlyer_Click" Content="Voir le flyer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonViewFacebookPage" Click="buttonViewFacebookPage_Click" Content="Page Facebook de l'évènement" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,5"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

I want the scrollview to have a height that adapts with device screen size.

Comment: It's all in your layout dude, share some xaml.

Comment: When you fix the height of ScrollViewer, it makes sense that irrespective of text size you want it to occupy only a fixed size. When you want your ScrollViewer to occupy the size of TextBlock, then what is the point in using the Scroll ? Pls correct me if I am wrong. Give more details.